# Failed to run dockerfile -> unknown instruction: APT-GET

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile, apt

Alright, so I'm trying to create a kind of pipeline to put my application online at Amazon AWS.
I am using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS MAVEN_BUILD
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && |
    apt-get install git -y
WORKDIR /repositorio/
RUN git clone https://gitlab.com/booking_hub/grupo_04_bookinghub.git
COPY /repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/backend/APIrest/APIrest/pom.xml /build/
COPY /repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/backend/APIrest/APIrest/src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn clean install "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" && mvn package
FROM openjdk:17-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/APIrest-*.jar /app/APIrest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "APIrest.jar"]
```

I'm having the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5STq.png)

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  #outro container --- backend
  springweb:
    container_name: bookinghub
    build: . #preciso do Dockerfile para gerar a imagem
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - servers
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev

networks:
  servers:
    driver: bridge
```

This docker-compose is being called by a ansible-playbook file (from a management machine):

```
- hosts: backend
  become: yes
  tasks:
# 1
### task desnecessária para uso com docker, o mvn já está sendo puxado da imagem que irá rodar o docker
  # - name: "System : instalando o mvn"
  #   shell:
  #     cmd: "sudo mvn install"
  #     chdir: /home/ubuntu/backend
#1
  - name: "System: Atualizando o sistema"
    become: true
    shell:
      cmd: "apt-get update"
#2
  - name: "System: Instalando dependências do Docker"
    become: true
    apt:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    loop:
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg
      - gnupg-agent
      - lsb-release

#3
  - name: "Docker : adicionar chave GPG"
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present
#4
  - name: "Docker : adicionar repositório do instalador"
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
      state: present
#5
  - name: "Docker : instalacao"
    apt:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: latest
      update_cache: yes
    loop:
      - docker-ce
      - docker-ce-cli
      - containerd.io
      - docker-compose
#6
  - name: "Docker : instalar python e pip, Ansible precisa para poder iniciar e executar o Docker"
    apt:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: latest
      update_cache: yes
    loop:
      - python3
      - pip
#7
  - name: " Docker : Instalar recurso que o ansible  precisa para o docker"
    pip:
      name: docker
#Fim da  instalação do Docker

  handlers:
    - name: "System : reiniciar o Docker"
      service:
        name: docker
        state: restarted

    - name: Criar rede servers
      docker_network:
       name: servers
       driver: bridge
       state: present
       force: yes

- hosts: backend
  tasks:
    - name: "System: Executando o docker compose da aplicação Backend"
      become: true
      shell:
        cmd: "docker-compose -f docker-compose-java.yml up"
        chdir: /home/ubuntu/Backend
```

I am stuck in this error and don't know what to do. The official maven image says it runs a Ubuntu based image so APT-GET should've worked.

I tried to change the maven version to 3.8.1 where I found out that this version still used a Ubuntu based where APT-GET work but the same error occurred.

I expect the dockerfile to download a maven image, run a git clone of my project and build it inside the docker image (which will be called by a docker-compose file)

Comment: The error is a parsing error - so its your dockerfile - looks like you have a "|" instead of "\" making docker think `apt-get` as a dockerfile command instead of part of the previous `RUN` line

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Hello, the answer by @i0x539 solved the problem. I changed the image version I was using to 3.8.6-openjdk18 and found out that this is a RedHat OS, so I ran "microdnf install git -y" and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like https://hub.docker.com/_/maven is on oraclelinux which is redhat based.

See https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/ac292f26884bf2be9fe69f6e397da3b124c1e35c/openjdk-18/Dockerfile#L1

I think you should try https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/installing-software-packages#rpm and https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/installing-software-packages#yum as your package managers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer I changed the version I was using to 3.8.6-openjdk18 and found that it is a RedHat OS, which in the Dockerfile example he used "microdnf install git" so I did the same and it worked!

Comment: glad to hear it, if you believe my response could help other people please accept it when you can. good luck with your container setup